# Making index UI of grails app with springSecurity

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am new with grails and am developing a web application with grails.
I have installed springSecurity plugin for log in functionality. But the initial log in page is springSecurity provide is auth.gsp
And i was edited this auth.gsp file with my own UI structure like

But I want to make this auth.gsp as the index page which is loading when the application starts. How can i redirect index.gsp into auth.gsp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
"/"(view: "/index")
```

to

```
"/"(controller: 'login')
```

in your `UrlMappings.groovy`

Comment: This is working fine. But, now the Url is changing to http://localhost:8686/ProjectWork3/login/auth
is there any way to keep the url http://localhost:8686/ProjectWork3 only.

Comment: Then change to `"/"(view: "/login/auth")`